# Intel Galileo BSP Quark_EDKII error 4063

Tags: linux, intel, firmware, intel-galileo, bsp

Building the EDKII Firmware

> ./buildallconfigs.sh GCC44 QuarkPlatform

I get the errors listed below

after hitting a roadblock and not knowing where to go anyone any ideas?

running on

Python 3.3

CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   68:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.SDIO, 0x02) make: ***
>   [/home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.aml]
>   Error 255 Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.SDIO)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   69:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.URT0, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.URT0)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   70:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.USBD, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.USBD)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   71:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.EHCI, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.EHCI)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   72:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.OHCI, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.OHCI)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   73:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.URT1, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.URT1)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   74:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.ENT0, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.ENT0)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   75:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.ENT1, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.ENT1)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   76:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.SPI0, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.SPI0)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   77:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.SPI1, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.SPI1)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   78:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.GIP0, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.GIP0)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   85:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.PEX0, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.PEX0)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   86:             Notify (_SB.PCI0.PEX1, 0x02) Error    4063 -
>   Object does not exist ^  (_SB.PCI0.PEX1)
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   1218:             I2cSerialBus (0x20, ControllerInitiated, 0x00061A80,
>   AddressingMode7Bit, "\_SB.PCI0.GIP0.I2C_", 0, ResourceConsumer,,)
>   Error    4095 -
>   syntax error, unexpected PARSEOP_NAMESEG ^
>
> /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   1235:                 I2CSerialBus(0x20, ControllerInitiated, 100000,
>   AddressingMode7Bit, "\_SB.PCI0.GIP0.I2C_", 0, ResourceConsumer, , )
>   Error    4095 -
>   syntax error, unexpected PARSEOP_NAMESEG ^
>
> ASL Input: 
>   /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii
>   - 1301 lines, 48788 bytes, 568 keywords Compilation complete. 15 Errors, 0 Warnings, 0 Remarks, 31 Optimizations
>
> build.py...  : error 7000: Failed to execute command  make tbuild
>   [/home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables]
>
> build.py...  : error F002: Failed to build module
>     /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables.inf
>   [IA32, GCC44, DEBUG]
>
> - Failed - Build end time: 16:35:20, Mar.03 2015 Build total time: 00:00:13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with compiling ACPI tables. Crucial error message here is next:

> **ASL Input**: /home/mark/Quark_EDKII_v1.1.0/Build/QuarkPlatform/DEBUG_GCC44/IA32/QuarkPlatformPkg/Acpi/AcpiTables/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/Dsdt/Platform.iiii - 1301 lines, 48788 bytes, 568 keywords Compilation complete. **15 Errors**, 0 Warnings, 0 Remarks, 31 Optimizations

Probably your `ACPICA tools` outdated. You need to figure out, which version of ACPI compiler (from `ACPICA tools`) you should use. It's can be stated in build documentation for project you are building, or you can ask developers on corresponding mailing list. But first just try to update `ACPICA tools` to most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 to build the EDKII firmware and it seems the ACPICA tools in the Ubuntu "iasl" package support ACPI version 4. According to the document here: 
http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23962/eng/Quark_BSP_BuildandSWUserGuide_329687_007.pdf  a version supporting ACPI 5 is required.

So I removed the iasl package ("sudo apt-get remove iasl") and downloaded the sources from here: https://www.acpica.org/downloads

I unpacked and did a "make install" and now the firmware build seems to progress to completion.